# Problem with form database connectivity

Tags: database

Many people has asked the same question, I have read those things and mine is different,

I am trying to insert some values inside the database from the form but it's not getting inserted

I have a table in the database having 6 columns wanted to insert some values inside only of 4 columns

Table Name: `wp_contactus`

- 6 Columns

  - id
  - firstname
  - lastname
  - email
  - query
  - reg_date

This is the code for inserting only in the 4 columns

- 4 Columns

  - firstname
  - secondname
  - email
  - query

The code:

```
  <div class="wrap">
      <form action="" method="post">
          FirstName <input type="text" name="firstNametxt" value="" /><br/>
          LastName   <input type="text" name="lastNametxt" value="" /><br/>
          email <input type="text" name="email" value="" /><br/>
          Query <input type="text" name="query" value="" /><br/>
          <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
      <form method="post">
          <?php   
          global $wpdb;
                  $firstName = $_POST["firstNametxt"];
                  $lastName = $_POST["lastNametxt"];
                  $email = $_POST["email"];
                  $query = $_POST["query"];

                  echo $firstName;
          $contactus_table = $wpdb->prefix."contactus";

          $sql = "INSERT INTO $contactus_table (id, firstname, lastname, email,                                               

            query, reg_date) VALUES ('2', $firstName, $lastName, $email, $query,

            CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);";                  

            $wpdb->query($sql)) 

     ?>
     </form>
     </div>

     <?php
          }
          add_shortcode( 'CONUS', 'contactus_shortcode' );

     ?>
 <?php
      }
      add_shortcode( 'CONUS', 'contactus_shortcode' );

 ?>
```

Comment: Please format the code properly. This doesn't seem the full code as there are some brackets and curly braces remained open.

Comment: Please provide a full code + db fields data, Looks like you're creating a function for performing shortcode that does not represents here. Additionally, you can use $wpdb->insert() method. Refference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_rows

Comment: Please work on the format of your posts. It is a mess, sorry to say, and this makes your posts extremely hard to read. Posts in such poor format unfortanely attrack only negative feedback, which it already have, and someone has also flagged it as low quality. Please take your time and properly format your question before posting to get the best positive results back :-)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to insert the data before the form is submitted. Your code above had two forms, one for input and one with PHP.

You need to check whether the form has been submitted then action the PHP code or if not display the form.

```
$submitted_form = $_POST['submit'];

if(isset($submitted_form)) {
   //process and validate, then insert
} else {
   // nothing submitted, so lets display the form
  <form action="" method="post">
      FirstName <input type="text" name="firstNametxt" value="" /><br/>
      LastName   <input type="text" name="lastNametxt" value="" /><br/>
      email <input type="text" name="email" value="" /><br/>
      Query <input type="text" name="query" value="" /><br/>
      <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
}
```

this should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

[You're inserting raw POST data straight into an SQL query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zF8QT.jpg) - sanitize, sanitize, sanitize! The code below should get you started, but I would advise you add some additional checks (is the email valid? are the strings too long? etc.):

```
<?php

$errors =
$values = array();

if ( isset( $_POST['Submit'] ) ) {
    $fields = array(
        'firstNametxt',
        'lastNametxt',
        'email',
        'query',
    );

    foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
        if ( isset( $_POST[ $field ] ) ) { // Never assume a POST field will be set
            // Ensure the value is a string, POST data can be an array if the user is meddling
            $value = ( string ) $_POST[ $field ];

            // Strip slashes that WordPress adds
            $value = wp_unslash( $value );

            // Remove trailing/preceding whitespace
            $value = trim( $value );

            // Core WordPress function to check for invalid UTF-8, strip tags, remove line breaks etc.
            $value = sanitize_text_field( $value );
        } else {
            $value = '';
        }

        if ( ! $value )
            $errors[ $field ] = 'This field is required.';
        else
            $values[ $field ] = $value;
    }

    if ( ! $errors ) {
        $wpdb->insert(
            $wpdb->prefix . 'contactus',
            $values,
            '%s'
        );
    }
}

?>

<?php if ( $errors ) : ?>

    <p>Please ensure all fields are completed.</p>

<?php endif ?>

<form method="post">
    FirstName <input type="text" name="firstNametxt" value="" /><br/>
    LastName   <input type="text" name="lastNametxt" value="" /><br/>
    email <input type="text" name="email" value="" /><br/>
    Query <input type="text" name="query" value="" /><br/>
    <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And [read up on the codex for safely inserting into tables using `wpdb::insert()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_rows)